# jQuery fade out variable and element by class

Tags: jquery, class, variables, element, fadeout

Anyway to include both in a function? I imagined this would work, but it didn't

```
var slide = $('.z:visible'),
    next  = slide.next();

$(next, '.h').fadeOut(400);
//as opposed to next.fadeOut(400); $('.h').fadeOut(400);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is accomplished with the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
var slide = $('.z:visible');
slide.next().add('.h').fadeOut(400);
```